# Почему у одного из модераторов не отображается символ ромба?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, модерация, кэширование

Сегодня я зашел на страницу [выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election), и заметил, что у модератора [A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k) не отображается голубой алмазик. Это баг?

[image: mod_bug]

Comment: Это кэш, причем клиентский. Ctrl+F5 помогает

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Проблема вызвана багом или ошибкой, которая больше не воспроизводится

Comment: статус "так-задумано" на вопросе с таким провокационным заголовком выглядит двусмысленно)

Comment: А надо лишь исправить провокационный заголовок на нормальный

Comment: @Qwertiy, насколько я знаю, вопросы о проблемах кэша в итоге помечаются как «статус-не-воспроизводится», ведь через некоторое время проблема действительно уже не воспроизводится (без каких-либо дополнительных телодвижений). «Так-задумано» же подразумевает, что ситуация должна была сохраниться.